# Internet Speed on Router vs Device

Tags: networking, router, internet, internet-connection, fios

Moderator feel free to move to appropriate forum.

Recently got Verizon FIOS for parent's home.

Moved from 50mpbs upload and download to 1GB upload and download.

I plugged laptop into Router using Ethernet cable while everyone is asleep and no one is using Internet.

There are discrepancies with speed test.

[Speedtest by Ookla](http://beta.speedtest.net/): 95 Mpbs download / 94Mpbs upload

[Router Speed Test: Verizon](https://www.verizon.com/SpeedTest/routertest.aspx): 948 Mpbs download / 936 Mpbs upload

[Device Speed Test: Verizon](https://www.verizon.com/SpeedTest/SpeedTest.aspx?IIFlow=true): 95 Mpbs download / 114 Mpbs upload

QUESTION: Are results normal? If so, how to get faster speeds to device? Are there other questions I should ask Verizon (one is lucky to get a representative who understands their own product)

Comment: [Verizon Fios](https://www.verizon.com/home/fios/) currently offers 100, 150, 300 and 500 Mbps: which was purchased? I can only infer that the router speed test measures either the speed of your local network link to the router, or in some way establishes the maximum speed that the router model could support if the connection were upgraded.

Comment: @AFH 1 Gigabit was purchased. Both Upload and Download.

Comment: According to their site, this is not an available connection speed.

Answer (score 1):

can you verify at what speed your ethernet is running? it seems to me that your router or your device (likely this one) has only support for 100mbit/s ethernet (and not 1000mbit/s). if that is the case you just need to get a new network-adapter that supports the higher bandwidth.